# How create new col by increment it based on MIN(DATE) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, auto-increment

i would like to create new column based on date. If it's the MIN(DATE) then new_col = 0 else new_col = 1 or 2 or 3 etc.

So i've this table :

| customer_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 2020-12-01 |
| 2 | 2020-03-02 |
| 3 | 2020-04-06 |
| 1 | 2020-07-06 |
| 1 | 2020-08-12 |

and i want this output :

| customer_id | MIN(date) | date | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-03-02 | 2020-12-01 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-03-02 | 2020-03-02 | 1 |
| 3 | 2020-04-06 | 2020-04-06 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-07-06 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-08-12 | 2 |

So i would like to increment this new column by 1 for each date group by MIN(DATE).

Thanks by advance for your help

Comment: What version of Mysql do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use window function:

```
select * , row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by date) -1 new_col
from table
```